# Fonts look jumbled up in iPhone X while it looks good in iPhone 7

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, display

I have an app being developed in React Native and on compilation, it looks good in iPhone 7 but gets jumbled in iPhone X. I understand there has been size and resolution changes from iPhone 7 to iPhone X and read about something called, safe area. Tried to fix using those but not sure how to approach this issue. I am not an app developer so..

[image: iPhoneX looks like this]

[image: iPhone 7 looks normal]

Comment: us can use https://github.com/vitalets/react-native-extended-stylesheet, this library allow you define different font size for different device size

Comment: @Nima Thank you for your response.It was an issue with auto scaling and app layout not being handled properly when the fonts were increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem when autoscaling is on by default which is the case with React Native based apps. You either can turn it off to turn off the accessibility entirely or work with app layout to make sure it can handle bigger fonts when the fonts are made bigger through phone settings for people with eye issues.